# JavaScript function not work with posted html data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have 2 pages one called index.html that include all css, jquery libraries and main javascripts. other page call size.php that will generate html data and send to index.php page when call main ajax.

index.php

```
<head> 
   <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
   </head>
   <body>

   <div class="select2-container ">
      <form >
      <select id="select" class="form-control">
       <optgroup label="English / Tamil"><option value="1">5x2 - Front Box - English</option>
          <option value="2">8x2 - Front Box - English</option>
          <option value="3">6x10 -  Strip English / Tamil</option>
          <option value="4">16x5 - English</option>
       </optgroup>
      </select>
      </form>
      <div id="preview">
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 padding-no"  ><img src="imgs/info-icon.png" id="download-tip" title="not set"/></div>
      </div>


      <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  

      <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){ 

     //select change
     $("#select").change(function(){
        var size  = $(this).select2('data').id; 

         $.ajax({
            url: 'sizes.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { size_id : size  },
            dataType: 'html',
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#preview').html('<img src="css/loading.gif" />');
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {

                    $('#preview').html(data); 
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#preview').html(textStatus);
            }
        });

        });
    $('#size-tip').tooltip({
            placement: "top", 
            container: 'body'
        });


    });

    </script>
```

size.php

```
 <?php
    require_once('include/db.php');
    $size_id= $_POST['size'];  
    ?>  
    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 padding-no" >
       <img src="imgs/info-icon.png" id="size-tip" title="<?php echo $size_id;?>" />
    </div>
```

problem is when I select from the select box then ajex works properly but in the response html (#size-tip) tool tip not working. in size.php I have loaded any jquery libraries.

every time I got this issue with when I use ajax html jquery
need your help

Comment: You can't bind the event on dynamic content. Use jquery "on" function in tooltip function

Comment: Add the tooltip function jQuery response, this might solve your problem.

Comment: amit how to use "on" function here ? Rahul tooltip function is already in bootstrap.js, but in joomla, wordpress , and other mvc frameworks how they handle this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<head> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 </head>
   <body>

   <div class="select2-container ">
      <form >
      <select id="select" class="form-control">
       <optgroup label="English / Tamil"><option value="1">5x2 - Front Box - English</option>
          <option value="2">8x2 - Front Box - English</option>
          <option value="3">6x10 -  Strip English / Tamil</option>
          <option value="4">16x5 - English</option>
       </optgroup>
      </select>
      </form>
      <div id="preview">
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 padding-no"  ><img src="imgs/info-icon.png" id="download-tip" title="not set"/></div>
      </div>
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){ 

     //select change
     $("#select").change(function(){
        // alert('ddd');

        var size  = 100; 
         //alert(size);
         $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/sizes.php',
            type: 'POST',
             dataType: 'html',
            beforeSend: function() {
                //$('#preview').html('<img src="css/loading.gif" />');
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                     alert(data);
                    $('#preview').html(data); 
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#preview').html(textStatus);
            }
        });

        });
   // $('#size-tip').tooltip({
     //       placement: "top", 
      //      container: 'body'
      //  });


    });

    </script>
```

Comment: i made it simple to show only tooltip i just added one library at the top and coomentd ur some code please modify according to ur need

Comment: Thank your answer, actually but I need to bind dynamic content work with javacript.

Comment: i think what actually iam getting is this that u want to show tooltip on the data which u are getting from ajax response after data gets appended inside any element(div,p,span).and when u will mousehover on it its tile will be shown as tootip. Am i right?

Comment: I fixed it using jquery load() function , that can that can work with dynamic js